# How to query for many facets in single elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to query the distribution of the top n values for many object fields in single query

My object in elastic search looks like:

```
obj: {
  os: "Android",
  device_model: "Samsung Galaxy S II (GT-I9100)",
  device_brand: "Samsung",
  os_version: "Android-2.3",
  country: "BR",
  interests: [1,2,3],
  behavioral_segment: ["sport", "lifestyle"]

}
```

The following query brings the distribution of the values for specific field with number of appearances of this value only for the UK users

```
  curl -XPOST http://<endpoint>/profiles/_search?search_type=count -d '
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
        "country" : "UK"  
    }
 },
 "facets": {
    "ItemsPerCategoryCount": {
      "terms": {
          "field": "behavioral_segment"
      }
  }
  }
}'
```

How can I query for many fields  - for example I would like to get a result for behavioral_segment and device_brand and os in single query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the facets section of the query, you should use the `fields` parameter.

```
"facets": {
  "ItemsPerCategoryCount": {
    "terms": {
      "fields": ["behavioral_segment","device_brand"]
    }
  }
}
```

That should solve your problem, but of course it might not garantee the coherence of the data

Comment: Great, Thanks! But in that case, How can I identify which value belongs to which field?

Comment: If you want to use facets on more than one field, you can't! You'll have to use 2 separate facets in the same query.

Comment: Thanks, just used it. Also I've seen that the facets are deprecated in latest version. According to docs the api should use aggregations

Comment: Exactly, facets are deprecated, but aggregations are based on facets.